# Installation of distcc 3.1 on Sun Solaris

Tags: solaris, distcc

I am trying to install distcc 3.1 on one of the Sun Solaris platform.

After extracting the files to a folder I run configure (script which basically checks the required configuration). 
This script throws out the following error

`make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 471: Unexpected end of line seen`

after this if I run make or make install command I get another error and I am not able to proceed with the installation. Please help me with the correct installation process or guide me on how to resolve this Make issue.

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when the version of distcc installed is not compatible with your O.S. Install the package again this time for your own OS. Example - I installed distcc 2.13 for solaris 9 from www.sunfreeware.com.

I hope this helps !!

Thanks